# sub. relative/ valeur du subjonctif

Tags: temps-grammatical, subjonctif, pronoms-relatifs, subordonnées, mode-grammatical

Dans la phrase suivante:

> Il semblait que ce fût une personne enchantée de qui dépendissent le bonheur, la vie ou la fortune de tous

de qui dépendissent: s'agit-il d'une subordonnée relative? Le 'qui' remplace quel sujet? Et comment justifie-t-on l'emploi du subjonctif "qui dépendissent"?

Comment: Bienvenue sur French Language. Il est d'usage de donner ses sources quand on fait une citation. Lis [l'aide en ligne](https://french.stackexchange.com/help/) et  particulièrement [cette page](https://french.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) *Have you thoroughly searched for an answer before asking your question? Tell us what you found and why it didn’t meet your needs*. Penses-tu que c'est une subordonnée relative ? Que penses-tu toi que  « qui » remplace ? As-tu cherché quand on emploie le subjonctif pour essayer de justifier son emploi ?  Clique sur *edit* pour modifier ta question.

Comment: Et j'oublais, une seule question à la fois. [*Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer. Avoid asking multiple distinct questions at once.*](https://french.stackexchange.com/help/closed-questions)

Answer (score 2):

C'est une subordonnée relative puisqu'elle commence par le pronom relatif *qui* introduit par la préposition *de*.

Le pronom « qui » est complément d'objet indirect du verbe « dépendissent », pas sujet. L'antécédent de « qui » est « une personne enchantée ». Lorsque le pronom relatif est introduit par une préposition, il prend dans certains cas une forme différente suivant si l'antécédent est animé (personne, animal) ou inanimé (chose, concept). Pour la préposition *de*, cela donne « la personne ***de qui*** je dépends » ou « la personne ***dont*** je dépends » ou « la personne ***de laquelle*** je dépends », mais forcément « la voiture ***dont*** je dépends » ou « la voiture ***de laquelle*** je dépends ». On peut utiliser *de qui* ou *dont* pour une personne, mais seulement *dont* pour un objet. On peut aussi utiliser *duquel/de laquelle/desquels/desquelles* lorsqu'il s'agit d'une personne ou d'une chose parmi un certain ensemble.

Le sujet de « dépendissent » est « le bonheur, la vie ou la fortune de tous ». Dans cette phrase, il peut être placé avant ou après le verbe. On est obligé de mettre le complément d'objet indirect *de qui* au début de la proposition parce qu'il contient le pronom relatif. Du coup, on a tendance à mettre le sujet après le verbe si le sujet est long : on met toujours le sujet avant le verbe si c'est un pronom, mais c'est optionnel lorsque le sujet est plus compliqué, et ici, le sujet est très long et on est presque obligé de le mettre après.

Le verbe est au subjonctif parce qu'il fait parti de l'hypothèse introduite par « il semblait ». On pourrait aussi mettre le verbe à l'indicatif, mais le sens serait différent. « Il semblait que ce fût une personne enchantée de qui dépendent le bonheur, la vie ou la fortune de tous » signifierait qu'il existe des personnes enchantées dont dépendent le bonheur, la vie et la fortune de tous, et que « il semblait » porte seulement sur le fait que la personne désignée par « ce » est une de ces personnes.